# .Net Core 3.1 Localization not working with Accept-Language Header for other cultures except english after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-localization

I have implemented localization in .Net Core 3.1 as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1. It's working fine on local using
QueryString & Accept-Language HTTP header on local but **after deployment** not working with  Accept-Language HTTP header for other cultures except english.
Code Changes

- In Startup.cs

// in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()

services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = GetSupportedCultures();
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
```

// in configure method

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
```

// helper method

```
private IList<CultureInfo> GetSupportedCultures()
{
    var cultures =  Configuration.GetValue<string>("SupportedCultures")?.Split(",");
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
    foreach (var culture in cultures)
    {
        supportedCultures.Add(new CultureInfo(culture.Trim()));
    }
    return supportedCultures;
}
```

// in appsettings.json

```
"SupportedCultures": "en,fr,de,el,es"
```

Request Header in browser network tab

```
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr-CA;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,es;q=0.5,el;q=0.4,en-GB;q=0.3,en-US;q=0.2
```

Comment: After adding log found - Not getting Accept-Language in request on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good to me. Did you check whether you are getting `Accept-Language` HTTP headers from your request after deployment? If you are not getting it then you need to check whether you are using any proxy server or CDN.

If that is the case, you are required to whitelist the `Accept-Language` in headers as per below:

[image]